# Getting Error in jquery js while loading an external jsp into the current page DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a requirement to load an external jsp page which will have script tags with functions defined. I have to load a part of the jsp page into the requesting page's div and also load the scripts into the page and invoke those script functions in the current page..

I have tried using jquery ajax call with GET type and async:false. But when load the returned data into the current page DIV getting jquery js error in globalEval function.

The firebug points to this part of the jquery js source..

```
// Evaluates a script in a global context
// Workarounds based on findings by Jim Driscoll
// http://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2009/09/08/eval-javascript-global-context
    globalEval: function( data ) {
        if ( data && rnotwhite.test( data ) ) {
            // We use execScript on Internet Explorer
            // We use an anonymous function so that context is window
            // rather than jQuery in Firefox
            ( window.execScript || function( data ) {
                window[ "eval" ].call( window, data );
            } )( data );
        }
    },
```

Below is the code snippet i am using..

```
$.ajax({url:'/web/guest/campaignreports',success:function (data) {

                    alert('hi');




                    dialogData = $(data).find('.portlet-content');

                    $('body div#second_popupcontent').html(data);

                    Demographicshome_charts();
                    $('body div#second_popupcontent').dialog({title: "Pop Up",width: 600,modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            "Cancel":function(){
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                            }
                        });

                    },cache:false,async:false,type:'GET'});
```

Kindly guide me and let me know what i am doing wrong and help me to solve this issue and get my requirement working...

Answer (score 0):

Have you find which line of your script trigger the error?

Why do you initialize dialogData? Especially there! Why not:

```
$('#second_popupcontent').html(data);
dialogData = $('#second_popupcontent .portlet-content');
```

Maybe your problem come from here...

Also, it's a bad practice to add extra selector like 'body div#second_popupcontent'; '#second_popupcontent' is enough and often is quicker.

Comment: u mean i can load the jsp page into div and then extract a part of that and use it popup for popup...Is it so???

Comment: Yes you can. In your example, you extract a part of the response but you don't use it... you inject data, not dialogData in #second_popupcontent.

Comment: actually i have to load a part of the jsp(but include all the scripts from that jsp page)into the current page div(DOM element) and use that div for showing it as a popup...Is that way possible to do..